# Problem with rounding in SurfaceViewRenderer

Tags: java, kotlin, webrtc, surfaceview

I ran into a problem that I cannot round the corners of a SurfaceViewRenderer, if it lies on another SurfaceViewRenderer.

**Issue:**
[image]
As you can see my all corners are rounded but my desired output is to have top corners rounded. See desired output example below

**Desired Output**
[image]

Comment: have you solved this?

Comment: Did you find the solution?